# Filling missing data on Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, time-series, stock

I'm trying to compare data sets of two different stocks but they have missing data causing their dates to be mixed up. Stock A as a result has a short column for time and price than stock B. I'd like to balance these columns out so they have the same amount of values in them. I tried using an if statement but it fell short since the stock A sometimes had multiple rows of data missing consecutively.
Ideally, the spaces where the data is missing would be filled with the values that preceded the gap. For instance, if the prices went:
1, 2, 3, 4, blank, 5
It would be changed to:
1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5
This would be easy to do if the blanks were actually blank but they're filled with values.

```
IF(B80=D80,C80,C79)
```

[image: Excel Sheet Screenshot]

Comment: How do you want to fill that missing data in both columns? You need to explain better the logic behind the process and add an expected output example.

Comment: Maybe `VLOOKUP` to find the matching date?